# pandas merge shows unexpected results using index on left and column on right

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to merge two pandas DataFrames, one on its index, the other on a regular column:

```
import pandas as pd

df_left = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'y' : [2, 4]
    },
    index = [7, 8]
)

df_right = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'a' : [42, 7],
        'b' : ['foo', 'bar']
    }
)

df_left.merge(
    df_right, 
    left_index=True,
    right_on='a',
    how='left', 
    indicator=True
)
```

The result is not quite what I expected:

```
        y   a   b       _merge
1.0     2   7   bar     both
NaN     4   8   NaN     left_only
```

- column 'a' in the result contains the values from df_left.index
  My expectation: [7, NaN].
- The index of the result contains [1.0, NaN]
  My expectation: [7, 8]
  (The documentation doesn't say anything about the index of the result, but I expected this anyway...)

(I could not reproduce any surprising behavior when merging on both indexes, or merging with regular columns on both sides.)

What's going on here? Wrong Expectations?

working with  `pandas==0.25.0` and `python=3.6.8`

Comment: the ourput result in sample seems wrong. I run the code the index is [1,1,] rather than [1,Nan]. I regard this as a normal result with your code. Try to set index after the merge.

Comment: @Yuan: I would not regard it as normal, that you and I see different results. Are you using the same pandas version? And python version, too?

Comment: "The index of the result contains [1.0, NaN]", the index is from right column, I checked your version, it is a bug fix. From version 25, missing index will be assigned to `na`. Check the link:https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/whatsnew/v0.25.0.html#series-explode-to-split-list-like-values-to-rows     My version is 24, so it reported [1,1], but in any version, it wont be [7,8]

Comment: As for column['a'], [7,8] must be there because you assign `how='left'`, all element in the left df must hold. Next rule is `left_index=True & right_on='a', this makes left index and right colunm['a'] become the shared column.